# Weight spaces of modules over Lie algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

I know that an irreducible infinite-dimensional weight module over the Virasoro algebra in which it has a non-zero finite-dimensional weight space, then all its weight spaces have finite dimension. Does this result extend to finite-dimensional simple Lie algebras over complex numbers?

> See a later, but more precisely worded [**duplicate**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336537/irreducible-weight-modules-for-finite-dimensional-lie-algebras).

Comment: Ptonsbly the question needs a more precise formulation, to express "this result" clearly.    Then the answer is likely to be "yes".

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336537/irreducible-weight-modules-for-finite-dimensional-lie-algebras. The other question is newer, but worded better, so I am voting to close this one (err, I can't, because in the new MO, an accepted answer is required to close duplicates).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as for the reasons in @VictorProtsak's comment